# Api.ai speech recognition and NLU in one request

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, google-speech-api, dialogflow-es

I'm building a robot for human interaction. And I need it to be swift and responsive when it comes to voice interface. And the Internet channel is expected to be not so reliable in terms of speed. Ping time is ~130ms on average, but sometimes it peaks to ~1000ms

I decided to choose api.ai because I already use Google Speech Recognition and since they most likely are integrated somehow and I saw in demo that there is voice input. So, instead of making 2 web requests, I'd make only one and gain responsiveness, right?

Now I can't find it on the website and the method for voice input says it's deprecated and going to be removed soon. After searching the web it seems that indeed they decided to remove it and focus only on NLU.

So, what do I do now? Is there any way to achieve it with api.ai or any other service? That seriously might be a deal breaker, to move NLU offline and use for example rasa.ai.

[Topic on their forum](https://discuss.api.ai/t/is-voice-requests-still-being-supported-by-api-ai/4044)

[Issue on github](https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-ios-sdk/issues/19)

Comment: You meant the API.AI API doesn't take voice (audio file) requests anymore?

Comment: @BelaVizy yes, look at this: https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-ios-sdk/issues/19

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of platforms that do speech recognition as well as NLU:

- [wit.ai](https://wit.ai)
- [Amazon Lex](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/)